# Menu automaticall show and hide on touchstart event for android 4.2

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, backbone-events

I have one Hamburger menu clicking now my requirement is when user tap on menu icon then menu should be open and again user tap on menu then it will be hide.

**Following code is working perfectly in Android except 4.2.2 version.**

```
var homeView = Backbone.View.extend({ 
            template: _.template(homeViewTemplate),
            initialize: function () {
            },
            events: {
                'touchstart #menu-toggle': 'toggleMenu'
            }, 
            // Toggle Hamburger Menu
            toggleMenu: function (e) {
                if ($("#container").hasClass("menu")) {
                    console.log('Close');
                    this.$el.find("#main").show();
                } else {
                    console.log('Open');
                    this.$el.find("#main").hide();
                }
                e.stopPropagation();
                return false;
            }
});
```

**In Android 4.2.2 when i click on menu icon menu will open and immediately hide. i have to prevent auto hide.**

I am using PhoneGap, Backbone and jQueryMobile

Can anybody has idea what is wrong in this code.